# Calculate Total of Items in List

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to convert the following procedure to use Linq, but I'm not sure how to accomplish it, ForEach or Sum?

```
    public int GetBalance()
    {
        int balance = 0;

        foreach (IDenomination denomination in Account)
        {
            balance += denomination.Currency * denomination.BillCount;
        }

        return balance;
    }
```

Account is a property in the class:

```
public List<IDenomination> Account { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or you could do it in two steps, like you do it now. First calculate for each denomination and then sum:

```
int balance = Account.Select(denom => denom.Currency * denom.BillCount).Sum();
```

Comment: Another awesome answer, thank you!  I'm still somewhat of a noob with Linq so I really appreciate the help!

Comment: btw. Free upside of doing things this way: Linq's Sum() does overflow detection for you. Downside of doing things this way: its probably a little bit slower than your original foreach. (and of course the major upside is that reads better)

Comment: Agreed, it's definitely a bit of a trade off.

Comment: @Hirle You can actually do the lambda inside the Sum: `var balance = Account.Sum(denom => denom.Currency * denom.BillCount);`

Comment: Cool, didnt know that!

Comment: @danlyons This should be the answer!

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `Aggregate` extension method:

```
int balance = Account.Aggregate(0, (old, item) => old + item.Currency * item.BillCount);
```